TalkBack reads background content even with role="dialog" and aria-modal="true"
When using TalkBack on Android devices to interact with a web page, I observed that even with role="dialog" and aria-modal="true" properly set on a modal dialog, TalkBack still reads the background content outside the dialog. This issue specifically occurs in web environments and disrupts accessibility for users relying on screen readers.
Steps to Reproduce:
Open a web page with a modal dialog implemented using role="dialog" and aria-modal="true". Activate TalkBack. Navigate to the modal dialog and explore its content using TalkBack. Observe that TalkBack reads content outside the modal dialog. Expected Behavior: When aria-modal="true" is applied to a modal dialog on a web page, TalkBack should restrict the screen reader to only the content within the dialog and prevent it from accessing background elements.
To address the problem where TalkBack reads background content on web pages even with role="dialog" and aria-modal="true, I have tried the following solutions:
Setting aria-hidden="true" on Background Content
Applied aria-hidden="true" to all elements outside the modal dialog when it is active.
Result: This prevents TalkBack from reading background content but requires extensive DOM manipulation for larger projects, making it challenging to maintain.
Using the inert Attribute on Background Content
Added the inert attribute to all elements outside the modal dialog, effectively disabling focus and interaction on background content.
Result: This approach works, but implementing it across a large-scale project requires significant structural changes and additional JavaScript polyfills for browser compatibility.
